# Multiple web apps with Docker architecture

Tags: docker, architecture, dev-to-production

I have multiple web apps, all of them running on Apache, many of them using PHP, MySQL, node, etc.

I'm not currently using Docker, but I would like to use it, and I would like to know what would be the best architectureto use.

I suppose that in my localhost I should create a container with Apache, and all the applications would be using it (am I wrong?). The same with MySQL if the application uses it.

But then, what happens when I want to deploy my projects (or some of them) into a production environment? I'm currently using Microsoft Azure WebApps, and I don't thing that my 'localhost' setup will be valid. I suppose that in production, each project should have its own Apache, but this changes my Docker setup, and I don't think this is the Docker philosophy.

So, how should I structure my architecture?

Comment: Suggest you to read more on docker and understand it better. Docker should help you to keep things uniform across environments.

Comment: Yes, is for this reason that I'm asking this question, I would like to know how can I keep things uniform across environments

Comment: Your question is basically how docker works. For that you should read docker tutorial and try it. SO encourages you to try things and ask a specific question. This is very broad.

Comment: No, this is not my question, my question is if I should use one apache (for example) container for each web app or if I can share it between apps and how can I manage this in production environments. I've tried both arquitectures in my localhost but I want to know whats the best practice